# Bring object to the front, in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have the below code, which is basically animating object across the screen, when roll-over happens it pauses the anim, and displays some information. Everything works fine, but when its paused, i wold like that current object to be 'on top' so other items run behind.

I have looked at setChildIndex, but didn't have much luck.

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.*;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
import fl.motion.Color;

public class carpurchase extends Sprite {

    public function carpurchase() {

        var carX = 570;


        //Set cars
        var car1:fullCar = new fullCar();
        car1.info.alpha = 0;
        //var c:Color = new Color();
        //c.setTint(0xff0000, 0.8);
        //car2.car.transform.colorTransform=c;
        car1.x = carX;
        car1.y = 280;
        car1.info.title.text = "test";
        car1.info.desc.text = "test";
        addChild(car1);
        car1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, carPause);
        car1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, carContinue);
        function car1Reset():void {
            Tweener.addTween(car1, {x:carX, time:0, onComplete:car1Tween});
        }
        function car1Tween():void {
            Tweener.addTween(car1, {x:-120, time:2, delay:3, transition:"linear", onComplete:car1Reset});
        }
        car1Tween();


        var car2:fullCar = new fullCar();
        car2.info.alpha = 0;
        var c:Color = new Color();
        c.setTint(0xff0000, 0.8);
        car2.car.transform.colorTransform=c;
        car1.x = carX;
        car2.y = 175;
        car2.info.title.text = "test";
        car2.info.desc.text = "test";
        addChild(car2);
        car2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, carPause);
        car2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, carContinue);
        function car2Reset():void {
            Tweener.addTween(car2, {x:carX, time:0, onComplete:car2Tween});
        }
        function car2Tween():void {
            Tweener.addTween(car2, {x:-120, time:3, delay:0, transition:"linear", onComplete:car2Reset});
        }
        car2Tween();



        function carPause(e:MouseEvent):void {
            Tweener.pauseTweens(e.target);
            Tweener.addTween(e.target.info, {y:-150, alpha:1, time:.5, transition:"easeout"});
        }   
        function carContinue(e:MouseEvent):void {
            Tweener.addTween(e.target.info, {y:10, alpha:0, time:.5, transition:"easeout"});
            Tweener.resumeTweens(e.target); 
        }
    }
}
```

Any help welcome

Comment: I have the same problem any help would be much apreciated! setChildIndex(evento.target,numChildren – 1); This doesnt work it marks this error: Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 6 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before 1.

Answer (score 8):

Just use addChild() on that specific instance. It will be placed to the 'top'

From the help files:

> Adds a child DisplayObject instance to this DisplayObjectContainer instance. The child is added to the **front (top) of all other children** in this DisplayObjectContainer instance.

And yes, that works even if the object already is on the displaylist.

Comment: the simplest solution is often the best

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [setChildIndex](http://snipplr.com/view/14341/as3-setchildindex/)?

Answer (score 3):

```
function carPause(e:MouseEvent):void {
    setChildIndex(e.target, numChildren-1);
    Tweener.pauseTweens(e.target);
    Tweener.addTween(e.target.info, {y:-150, alpha:1, time:.5, transition:"easeout"});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry it has taken me so long to come back to you, been on another job. I have tried adding the line but get an error:
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
setChildIndex(e.target, this.numChildren-1);

Any help again welcome

Answer (score 2):

I searched for the same problem and found this old post.
I solved this problem on a nice way and just want to share it for people for future finding this post.

The problem was, that you try to set the childindex from the loader-object itself, but this is the worng place to set it. You need the parent path to get access in this case to all your cars.

Well, long story short:
Try these changes:
Create a new Sprite in the attributes channel (after classname)

```
// [...]
public class carpurchase extends Sprite {
   private var _sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
}
// [...]
// Add the cars to the sprite
  _sprite.addChild(car1); // replace this lines
//[...]
  _sprite.addChild(car2); // replace this lines
// Of course adding the sprite to your stage
  addChild(_sprite);
```

After it, access you current target by finding by the name and set it on top

```
_mc.setChildIndex(_mc.getChildByName(e.target.name), _mc.numChildren-1); // Set on top
```

May it, it helps someday someone

Comment: "May it, it helps someday someone" - It just did ! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `addChildAt`?

[Adobe Live Docs - addChildAt()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt())

Comment: Would this only work when adding the object to the stage? I would need them to change when paused, ie. that current object would have to be on top when roll-over occurs

Comment: Nope, it also works when used on something that is already a child.  Normally, if you do parent.addChildAt(child, n), you add child to position n, and increase by one the position of all the other children which were at n or above.  In effect, you slot the child in like a card into a deck.  If you do this when child is already a child of parent, it works exactly the same way, except it doesn't do the adding part, it just moves it to position n.

Comment: I have tried adding:

function carPause(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addChildAt(e.target, 6)
          Tweener.pauseTweens(e.target);
          Tweener.addTween(e.target.info, {y:-10, alpha:1, time:1, transition:"easeout"});
   }

But gives error, any ideas?